# How to work with dates using node js model and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm working in a project that uses nodejs API and mysql as database.
I need to make a query that returns all the data of the current month and another one that returns all data between a period.
To get all records, I'm doing this

```
ContractValue.findAll({
      where: {
        data: id
      },
      order: [['data', 'ASC']]
    })
```

The thing is I don't know how to put the conditions inside the where clause

Comment: Can you specify what ORM you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like you are using "Sequelize" as your ORM and from your question i can tell that the problem is that you don't know how to put where conditions.

*This should help you!*

```
ContractValue.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.and]: {a: 5},           // AND (a = 5)
      [Op.or]: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}],  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
      [Op.gt]: 6,                // id > 6
      [Op.gte]: 6,               // id >= 6
      [Op.lt]: 10,               // id < 10
      [Op.lte]: 10,              // id <= 10
      [Op.ne]: 20,               // id != 20
      [Op.between]: [6, 10],     // BETWEEN 6 AND 10
      [Op.notBetween]: [11, 15], // NOT BETWEEN 11 AND 15
      [Op.in]: [1, 2],           // IN [1, 2]
      [Op.notIn]: [1, 2],        // NOT IN [1, 2]
      [Op.like]: '%hat',         // LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.notLike]: '%hat',       // NOT LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.iLike]: '%hat',         // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive)  (PG only)
      [Op.notILike]: '%hat',      // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
      [Op.overlap]: [1, 2],       // && [1, 2] (PG array overlap operator)
      [Op.contains]: [1, 2],      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)
      [Op.contained]: [1, 2],     // <@ [1, 2] (PG array contained by operator)
      [Op.any]: [2,3]            // ANY ARRAY[2, 3]::INTEGER (PG only)
    },
    status: {
      [Op.not]: false           // status NOT FALSE
    }
  }
})
```

You can read more on the documentation (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html) and also you should really know the tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is [node module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) for working with mysql database,first you create mysql connection object:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();
```

then you can build your desired query with it:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'YOU CONDITIONS...', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ContractValue.findAll({
    where: {
        data: {
            [Op.between]: [start, end]
        }
    },
    order: [
        ['data', 'ASC']
    ]
})
```